# What's the difference between the `generate()` method and the new ControllerTestCase class in CakePHP 2?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, controller, components

Regarding unit testing in CakePHP, it seems to be two *main* ways of testing actions.

The first one is mocking the involved controller using the `generate()` method:

```
$Posts = $this->generate('Posts', array(
  'methods' => array(
    'isAuthorized'
  ),
  'models' => array(
    'Post' => array('save')
  ),
  'components' => array(
    'RequestHandler' => array('isPut'),
    'Email' => array('send'),
    'Session'
)
));
```

But [in CakePHP 2 a new `ControllerTestCase` class has been added](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers) to apparently ease this configuration:

```
class PostControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    public $fixtures = array('app.post');

    function testIndex() {
        $result = $this->testAction('/post/index');
        debug($result);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have found several issues when using components through the ControllerTestCase class. I would like to know what's the difference, if any, between these two approaches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is actually the same way, The `generate` method is used to configure the controller before using `testAction`, that way you will have control over what components, models or controller methods should be mocked before testing the action. The method `generate` is ony available in the `ControllerTestCase` class